# Error "Constant 'self.apiKey' used before being initialized" in Initializer

Tags: ios, swift, class, environment-variables

I have a class YoutubeAPIClient:

```
import Foundation

class YoutubeAPIClient {
    let apiKey: String?

    init?() {
        do {
            apiKey = try Environment().getValue(for: "YOUTUBE_API_KEY") as? String
        } catch {
            //TODO: Implement error handling
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

In the init method I am trying to initialise apiKey but it says:

```
Constant 'self.apiKey' used before being initialized
```

If it helps, I have included the Code for the Environment struct:

```
import Foundation

struct Environment {

    func getValue(for key: String) throws -> Any {

        guard let value = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment[key] else {
            throw GenericError.noValueForKeyInEnvironment
        }

        return value
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to return `nil` from `catch` or rethrow the error, otherwise your object will be uninitialized.

Comment: Lol, I thought I did :D Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the error otherwise the instance would end in undefined state (`apiKey` uninitialized in case of error).

Since your `init` is already failable, you can just return `nil`:

```
} catch {
    print(error)
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined apiKey as optional so it can't be nil at the time of initialisation, change it to var from let and it should work. Alternatively return nil from catch block to handle the error.

```
class YoutubeAPIClient {
    var apiKey: String?

    init?() {
        do {
            self.apiKey = try Environment().getValue(for: "YOUTUBE_API_KEY") as? String
        } catch {
            //TODO: Implement error handling
            print(error)
            fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```